# I am trying to use php echo to show div id

Tags: php

I made a header.php file that have a

```
<div id="contact-us">
```

but i want to change it so that it echo the page id into the header because each page have it's own id

for example

in header file

```
<div <?php echo $page_id; ?> ">
```

in contacts.php you would have

```
<?php $page_id = id="contact-us" ">
```

can you tell me what i did wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create an ID by echoing out a variable from php, you probably just want to do something like this:

```
<div id="<?php echo $page_id; ?>">
```

This way, the contents of `$page_id` will be set as the ID in your html code.  You can set the value of `$page_id` elsewhere using only one `=`, like so:

```
<?php $page_id = "contact-us"; ?>
```

Note that this code will have to come before you try to create the div with this id.  Your computer can't time travel, it needs to know what the value of the variable is before you try to use it.

Comment: if I use `<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="contact-us">
<!-- Page Descrription Begins-->
 <div class="page-desc-section"> <div class="row">`                      
   <div class="container"> in the page.php it shows how it should but when i add `<body> <div id="<?php echo $page_id; ?>">` to the header.php and `<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<? $page_id = "contact-us"; ?>
<!-- Page Descrription Begins-->
 <div class="page-desc-section"> <div class="row">` it don't show it how it should

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  You need to move `<? $page_id = "contact-us"; ?>` to before `<?php include("header.php"); ?>`

Comment: You need to set the variable before you include header.php. And you shouldn't use <? which is the short open tag and bad practice. Use    <?php whenever you initiate php in your script

Comment: You could also rewrite it as `<?php $page_id = "contact-us";  include("header.php"); ?>`  (with line breaks)

Answer (score 2):

You must set your variable before you use it, for example:

```
$page_id = 'Whatever';
```

Then you can use it:

```
  <div id="<?= $page_id; ?>">
```

Something like this:

```
<?php $page_id = id="contact-us" ">
```

won't work!